# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT and INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED when run application from android studio

Tags: android-studio, android, android-install-apk

I use android studio to create application name "chaiyaphum".

Then i run my app with device "ASUS fonepad7 k00z" and it's work well.

After that i create new project name "sampleapp" and run It's show error

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/abc.sampleapp
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

After that i run "sampleapp" again It's show error

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/abc.sampleapp
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

How to solve it's?

Comment: completely uninstall the app from your phone ensure that you dont have another app with the same package name

Comment: i uninstall "chaiphum" from my device and run "sampleapp" again it's still error.